# Make an extendable java program

Tags: java, jar

I'm making a java command prompt (like the Windows CMD).

But I want to make it possible for other developers to add some commands to my program by putting their own **.jar* files in a folder called "extensions".

I know this is possible because Minecraft can be modded with MC Forge like that *(by putting your mod jars in a folder called "mods")*

Example:

```
public class myExtension extends Extension {

    //A method called by my program
    @Override
    public void onLoad() {
        //Register a command in the main class...
        Command cmd = Commands.registerCommand("hello");

        //Add an event listener...
        cmd.addEventListener(new CommandEventListener() {
            public void onCommandExecute() {
                //Print "Hello World !" to console when the command is executed...
                Console.getConsole().print("Hello World !");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So now the guy who made this should be able to export this program as a jar file and put it in the "extensions" folder. But how can I make that my program register this jar as an extension ?

I you know the answer the please write it down ! Thank you !

Comment: You can use a ServiceLoader to load all the implementations of an interface in your class path which can include all the jars in a directory.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that ? (write an answer, not a comment) Thank you !

Comment: This tutorial has a demo https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html

Comment: Ok thank you. I will try that later !

Comment: @PeterLawrey the domain name has changed  
https://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.com/2013/03/java-serviceloader-example.html